# Hot reloading is disabled after put webpack-externals in webpack.config.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, webpack-externals

I'm using webpack in my `electron + reactjs` app.

It was very slow in dev so I did put externals: `[nodeExternals()]`

and now the speed of dev is OK but `electron` does not refresh the page after hot reloading. I mean hot reloading is working but the screen doesn't refresh after it.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens sometimes. You have to make use of the shake gesture to refresh sometimes.

Also, you can keep the `enable hot reloading` on so that it shows the live reloading when you save the code.

To enable live reloading

1. `react-native run-android` to run the app.
2. Then click on emulator and press CTRL + M (CMD + M on MacOS) or
   shake the Android device which has the running app.
3. Then select the Enable Live Reload option from the popup

Note: For some Mac system cmd + m doesn't work, Yan can run `adb shell input keyevent 82`

Hope this helps

You're good to go!!

Comment: Thanks but I'm working on electron and reactjs not react native